# Can I drive the car in UAE with my valid Indian license?

Tags: driving-licenses, uae

I am  planning to go to Abu Dhabi for 3 days. I have a valid Indian license.

Can I drive the car in the UAE with my Indian driving license? And what is the IDP? Where can I get this?

Answer (score 2):

[http://www.budget-uae.com/index.php?page=Standard+Information&id=133&act=viewpage&menu=2&mid=1](http://www.budget-uae.com/index.php?page=Standard%20Information&id=133&act=viewpage&menu=2&mid=1)

Drivers License Requirements:
All named drivers must hold a full, clean and valid driver’s license, valid for the country of issue for a minimum of 1 year. Drivers must have a current International license, which must be presented with their own national license. National license alone is accepted for the following countries: Britain, USA, France, Japan, Belgium, Holland, Switzerland, Denmark, Germany, Italy, Sweden, Greece, Austria, Ireland, Spain, Norway, Turkey, Canada, Poland, Korea, Finland, South Africa, Australia, New Zealand and Romania. However, we recommend that drivers obtain an international license as this may not apply to other Emirates with in the UAE. An International license is not accepted on its own.

Visitors from the Republic of Korea, Japan, Turkey and Greece are requested to have a translation of their license approved by the Council or Embassy.

AGCC National licenses are acceptable if they are holding AGCC passports. AGCC countries are as follows: Oman, Saudi Arabia, Qatar, Bahrain, Kuwait & UAE. Expatriates holding AGCC licenses are accepted provided they hold a residence visa for the country that has issued the license. AGCC license holders do not require an international license.

Expatriates living in the UAE on a residence visa require a UAE driver’s license. The UAE license must be held for a minimum of one year. If the UAE license is held for less than one year, a national license from the country of issue must be presented with the UAE license.

Abu Dhabi: All named drivers must hold a full, clean and valid driver’s license, valid for the country of issue for a minimum of 1 year. Drivers must have a current International license, which must be presented with their own national license. National license alone for all countries is not accepted.